# Add json file into object and saved into arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, json, object, arraylist

[image]I m trying get data from json file and saved as objects and then put into different arrylist, i m stuck on the point where i coundnt get "A320" into a obejcts, "type_ratings": [
"A320"
]

```
List<Crew> Allcrews = new ArrayList<>();
List<Pilot> pilotsList = new ArrayList<>();
List<CabinCrew> Cabincrews = new ArrayList<>();`
public void loadCrewData(Path p) throws DataLoadingException{
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(p);
    
        String jsonStr = "";
        String line = "";
        while ((line=reader.readLine()) !=null) 
        {
            jsonStr =jsonStr+line;
            }
        System.out.println ("Pilots Informations: ");
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        JSONArray pilots = jsonObj.getJSONArray("pilots");
            for(int j =0; j<pilots.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject pilot = pilots.getJSONObject(j);
                Pilot pil = new Pilot();
                pil.setForename(pilot.getString("forename"));
                pil.setHomeBase(pilot.getString("home_airport"));
                pil.setSurname(pilot.getString("surname"));
                pil.setRank(Rank.CAPTAIN);
                pil.setRank(Rank.FIRST_OFFICER);
                pil.setQualifiedFor(pilot.getString("type_ratings"));;
                
                pilotsList.add(pil);
                Allcrews.add(pil);
            
                
                System.out.println( "Forename: " +pilot.getString("forename"));
                System.out.println( "Surname: " +pilot.getString("surname"));
                System.out.println( "Rank: " +pilot.getString("rank"));
                System.out.println("Home_Airport: " + pilot.getString("home_airport"));
                System.out.println("type_ratings: " + pilot.getJSONArray("type_ratings"));  
 catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}[![JSONFile][1]][1]
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to get type_ratings as a String, but you should get an array, same way you do with pilots. Incidentally, have you considered using a framework like gson or Jackson, or did you specifically want to do this by hand?

Comment: I want to do this by hand, is there anyway i can do that ?

Comment: It looks like you are going the right way, I think you just need to use `pilot.getJSONArray("type_ratings")` then to be consistent with you approach, iterate through that, and call getString on each member. Now if each pilot has exactly one type rating you can just shorten it to `pil.setQualifiedFor(pilot.getJSONArray("type_ratings").getString (0))` but that assumes no empty arrays and only takes the first entry if more than one. Obviously adapt to your purposes

Comment: yes there is no empty arrys values, and your method works thank you !!

Comment: Brilliant, glad I could help - though I think you'd have cracked it before long

Comment: What is i had 3 values in the arraylist, should i just changed the index ? or using a loop ? is there a short way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, one option is to iterate exactly like you did with pilots, but use a different index as it is nested, and use the index in getString. If you are on Java 8 or higher, a streams approach is more concise IF a JSONArray can be used for getting a stream, I'll check....

Comment: Yes you can, so if your Pilot class has a List property for qualified for then you can do maybe `pil.setQualifiedFor(pilot.getJSONArray("type_ratings").stream().map(type -> type.getString()).collect(Collectors.toList())`. I'm not 100% sure that is correct but close enough I think

Comment: it make sensence to me, but my JsonArray is undefined for method Stream, so i think i have to use a different loop

Comment: Oh maybe so, I was looking at https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html which suggests JSONArray extends List

Comment: Ye, cant use extends list t.t

Comment: I find a way to do it, use for loop to loop though the length of jsonarray("type_ratings"), then get string from the length: for (int k =0 ; k<crew.getJSONArray("type_ratings").length(); k++) {
     c.setQualifiedFor(crew.getJSONArray("type_ratings").getString(k));;
     }

Comment: Yep, though a couple of things to be wary of - firstly if you assign the type ratings JSONArray to a variable outside the k indexed loop then your code will be slimmed down a bit - do it exactly like you declared the variable pilots in your earlier code then it is all consistent. Other thing is, if there are multiple type ratings you will be calling  c.setQualifiedFor each time which doesn't look right. If qualifiedFor is a list in Crew then I'd have a method addQualifiedFor in Crew rather than setQualifiedFor, and the method should add a value to the list

Answer (score 1):

The "type_ratings" key will return a JSONArray, not a String. This is because of the square brackets that surround the string, making it an array with 1 element. You could either change the JSON structure and remove the square brackets in order to only make it a String, or you could simply do  `pil.setQualifiedFor(pilot.getJSONArray("type_ratings")[0]);`, which will get the array, and return the first element, the string. Keep in mind that you should only do this if you know that type_ratings will always contain an array with 1 string.